# How to use gzip and http2 at the same time?

Tags: .htaccess, gzip, http2, http-compression

I'm doing webgl and use .ktx, a format extremly heavy when not gzipped.

The result of the loading size using http2 or http1.1 :

- https + http2 : 98mo, gzip doesnt work
- http  + http1.1 : 12mo, gzip work.

I was wondering if it was possible to use gzip and http2 at the same time?

In case, here my .htaccess ( relevant part ) :

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType model/gltf+json           .gltf
    AddType image/ktx                 .ktx
</Ifmodule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE   "model/gltf+json" \
                                    "image/ktx"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to stop you using gzip and http2 at the same time.

I can only guess you have the mod_deflate config only setup in your http vhost and not the https vhost.